# Can’t import font-face using webpack-4 file-loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I’m trying to import a font family into my react app using webpack `file-loader` and I keep getting this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/gilroy-bold/Gilroy-Bold.woff2'

I tried with `url-loader` but It’s the same.

Here is my file structure:

```
src
├── assets
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── gilroy-bold
│   │       ├── Gilroy-Bold.woff
│   │       └── Gilroy-Bold.woff2
│   ├── scss
│   │     └── 00_settings
│   │         └── _settings.fonts.scss
```

Webpack code:

```
{
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      outputPath: 'dist/fonts' 
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gilroy-Bold";
  src: url("./fonts/gilroy-bold/Gilroy-Bold.woff2"),
       url("./fonts/gilroy-bold/Gilroy-Bold.woff");
}

$font-family-accent: 'Gilroy-Bold';
```

I tried to follow this article: https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/fonts/ and a lot of other articles...

Comment: Could you expand on the error message you are getting, webpack can't find the module to load the fonts or can't find the fonts ?

Comment: I updated the error message. It seems that webpack can't find the font...

Comment: Looks like a url issue with the CSS I think. Edit: Ah yeah saw your answer, indeed !

Comment: I believe it is down to how the structure of the build from webpack is made and how the css files and the fonts are relative one to another after build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!
The problem was in the CSS font path which is weird regarding file structure...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gilroy-Bold";
  src: url("../fonts/gilroy-bold/Gilroy-Bold.woff2"),
       url("../fonts/gilroy-bold/Gilroy-Bold.woff");
}
```

I tried both `url(./)` and `url(../../)` but none of it works...